# SSRS Form/Report and Outer Join Results

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've been tasked with developing an enrollment form based on what benefit coverage employees have and do not have for the current year. Each page of the full report will show information for each individual employee with their typical information displayed at the top and then a listing of all available benefit types with a column next to it displaying a possible dollar figure that would indicate that employee is currently paying for that type of coverage. If this column is blank, that employee doesn't have that coverage.

This is what the form looks like:
[image]

I've written a query that employs left outer joins that returns a row for every benefit type from a master benefits table with some of those rows including the employee information and payment amount for 1 single employee. When I modify the query to retrieve results for more than one employee the results set only includes additional rows for benefits the extra employee is paying for. My thought is that I need to work out my dataset so that the total number of rows = number of employees * number of benefits. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way though.

Searched high and low but felt the need to reach out to a community I've learned so much from. Yeah, first time lurker post. Hopefully my situation has been described clearly and concisely.

**EDIT:** Here is the SQL that gets me the results I'm looking for on 1 person. When I ask for additional employees it only returns rows for benefits they pay on. The benefits table only has row for a benefit an employee pays for. The pr_deduction_master table has all benefits. Don't ask me about code designation... seems this implementation was poorly done in some respects.

```
select emp.a_name_last + ', ' + emp.a_name_first as 'Name',   emp.a_employee_number, emp.e_ssn, emp.e_email,
   emp.ed_p_address1, emp.ed_p_address_city, emp.ed_p_address_state, emp.ed_p_address_zip,
   a.a_deduction_code, a.a_ded_desc_long, b.a_employee_number, b.dh_emp_amount
from
(select distinct a_deduction_code, a_ded_desc_long from pr_deduction_master where a_deduction_code in 
(2000,2005,2007,2008,2010,2015,2020,2025,2027,2030,2040,2045,
2050,8055,8205,8210,8215,8220,8225,8230,8235,8240,8245,8250,
8252,8253,8255,8260,8280,8290,8295,8300,8305,8310,8315,8316,
8700,8701,8702,9100,9150,9151,9200)) a
left outer join
(select distinct a_employee_number, a_deduction_code, dh_emp_amount from pr_ded_history where a_employee_number in (603) and dh_pr_warr like '10816A') b
on a.a_deduction_code = b.a_deduction_code
left outer join
(select a_employee_number, a_name_last, a_name_first, ed_p_address1, ed_p_address_city, ed_p_address_state, ed_p_address_zip, e_ssn, e_email 
from pr_employee_master) emp
on b.a_employee_number = emp.a_employee_number
order by a_ded_desc_long
```

I hope this make anyone gag too much. Novice trying to get better here. I'll look into these suggestions. Really appreciate the responses.

**EDIT 2:** Following Daniel E's advice, "take [Employees] CROSS APPLY [Benefits] before left joining to the table of [EmployeeBenefits]" the cross apply shows me what's needed like below.

[Employee Table and Benefits Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPMAT.jpg)

When I try a variation of joins with the 3rd table, the deductions history table where each employees deductions are recorded for a month, I get undesired results. I'm looking to join that third table and display NULL on lines that employees didn't have that type of benefit deduction and then a dollar amount for benefits they paid on the previous period.

Comment: Post your SQL so that we have an idea what your table structure is and what the heck you are doing???

Comment: "total number of rows = number of employees * number of benefits."  why are you doing left outer joins? that might be your problem. a left join should give you what you need and you should only need one join. employee  left join benefits. a left outer join suggests you are eliminating rows which isnt getting you closer to your statement. ... but yeah. post some sample data, post your table structures if you need help.

Comment: Some schema information would probably help here. what do your source tables look like. Some sample data would also be good. Does the benefits table have a row for each benefit an employee pays for or also the $0s?

Comment: take [Employees] CROSS APPLY [Benefits] before left joining to the table of [EmployeeBenefits]

Comment: Bump.. added some information that might better explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what I was trying to achieve I went with something close to what Daniel E. said.

> take [Employees] CROSS APPLY [Benefits] before left joining to the
>   table of [EmployeeBenefits] – Daniel E.

The difference was that I utitilized CROSS JOIN. when I left joined the [EmployeeBenefits] table I was still having difficulty because I was trying to apply a filter to that table which in turn made it an INNER JOIN. This in turn was solved by nesting a query against that table with the filter.

Again, thank you all for your thoughts and help!!